# WPF left-click ContextMenu doesn't dissaepear on second click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've implemented a new behaviour for WPF button for using context menu with left click:

```
public class LeftClickContextMenuButtonBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_MouseDown), true);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button source = sender as Button;
        if (source != null && source.ContextMenu != null)
        {
            source.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = source;
            source.ContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
            source.ContextMenu.IsOpen = !source.ContextMenu.IsOpen;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.RemoveHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_MouseDown));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Left ContextMenu test">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <extensions:LeftClickContextMenuButtonBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Item A" />
            <MenuItem Header="Item B" /> 
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

It works fine, but I have a small problem - on a second click on the button (during the context menu is still opened), menu closes and immediately re-opens, but expected behaviour is to close the menu - `source.ContextMenu.IsOpen = !source.ContextMenu.IsOpen;`. So it seems that before MoseDown on button is fired, some other fuctionality closes the menu. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

I think i've found a solution:

```
<Button Content="Left ContextMenu test" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding ElementName=cm, Path=IsOpen, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolInverter}}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <extensions:LeftClickContextMenuButtonBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="cm">
            <MenuItem Header="Item A" />
            <MenuItem Header="Item B" /> 
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Where the BoolInverterConverter is defined as:

```
 public class BoolInverter : IValueConverter
 {
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
       if (value is bool)
         return !(bool)value;
       return value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

In this way when you click the button for the second time is not clicked but the context menu will close because it lost focus.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work - it seems, that ContextMenu.IsOpen is set to False before Button checks the vaue of IsHitTestVisible. I think, that parent window handles MouseDown, closes all context menus and after that routes the MouseDown event to the button, but at that time context menu is already closed, so IsHitTestVisible=true and tegrefore button handles MouseDown and reopens the menu...

Comment: I had tried this code in a little test app and it works well. Can you try only this example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void AssociatedObject_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.handled = true;  // handle the event
    Button source = sender as Button;

    //rest of the code ...
}
```

Best of luck !

Comment: I don't think that this will work. The problem is not associated with the event not handled.